# Intercept a celery task in before_task_publish and prevent it from getting published

Tags: python, celery

I wish to implement a solution, in which any tasks with ETA is getting stored in my database, instead of getting scheduled on the broker. I am doing this because of memory constraints on my workers, and the nature of workload I have. Celery schedules the ETA jobs in memory of workers.

I wish to achieve it using something like below

```
@before_task_publish.connect
def handle_tasks_with_eta(body, headers, **kwargs):
    # If the task is getting scheduled for future
    if headers.get("eta"):
        # Store the task in database with ETA, args, kwargs and sender
        # Prevent the task from getting scheduled <------ THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    else:
        pass
```

Raising a custom exception did not help. It is getting caught at - https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/bef4c1642586b89ed86ef61b5824cd7cfbd9aa55/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py#L289

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't overriding your `apply_async` method be more apt for this kind of job?

Comment: @JRajan - Do you mean monkey patching `Task.apply_async` and checking for `eta` in `kwargs`?

Comment: Yes. Something on those lines. Either monkeypatch the Task method or create a CustomTask class which inherits from celery's Task class and patch that to the celery module.

Comment: @JRajan - Yeah, I am considering as a plausible solution. Only not sure if patching the internal APIs like `apply_async` is a good idea. But yeah, that is one the solutions that I am looking at.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm looking to do the same thing.  Where'd you end up?

Comment: @chrislondon - I have added my implementation as an answer. Hope it helps. Please feel free to comment on the answer for any clarifications and I would be happy to reply to those.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be easier to approach the problem a bit differently. I have been working on a similar problem and decided to go with two queues, one for triaging jobs and another for executing them. I then used one worker with `-c1` option for handling the triage queue and another worker for doing the real work.

If you need to be able to trace results back to the request then you can specify the `task_id` when performing the triage task.

```
@app.task
def triage(args, kwargs, eta=None, task_id=None):
    if eta:
        # store in database
    else:
        other_task.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, task_id=task_id)

@app.task
def other_task(a1, a2, kw1=None):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: This is definitely an interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

For my implementation I used the `before_task_publish` hook you did in your original question.  I revoked the task if I save it into the database.  This way I can use the native `apply_async` function.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from celery.signals import before_task_publish
from django.utils import timezone


@before_task_publish.connect
def task_sent_handler(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    info = headers if "task" in headers else body
    if headers.get("eta"):
        eta = datetime.strptime(headers["eta"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        if eta - timezone.now() > timedelta(minutes=10):
            # Any tasks that are delayed over 10 minutes will be stored in the database until
            # it's time for them to run.
            from .models import DelayTask
            DelayTask.objects.create(
                task=headers["task"],
                eta=eta,
                argsrepr=headers["argsrepr"],
                kwargsrepr=headers["kwargsrepr"],
            )

            from app.celery import app
            app.control.revoke(info["id"])
```

I then have a `PeriodicTask` that runs every 10 minutes and sends any tasks that need to run in the next 10 minutes.

```py
@shared_task
def reschedule_tasks():
    tasks = DelayTask.objects.filter(eta__lte=timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=10))

    for task in tasks:
        # Grab all the tasks that are going to run in the next 10 minutes and send them to celery.
        task.send()
        task.delete()
```

Here's my `DelayTask` model

```py
import uuid
from ast import literal_eval

from celery.execute import send_task
from django.db import models

from app.shared.models import TimestampMixin


class DelayTask(TimestampMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    argsrepr = models.TextField()
    kwargsrepr = models.TextField()
    eta = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    def send(self):
        send_task(
            self.task,
            args=literal_eval(self.argsrepr),
            kwargs=literal_eval(self.kwargsrepr),
            eta=self.eta,
        )
```

Comment: This is really neat. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating an internal implementation to achieve task scheduling in a persistent data store. I created a class, which would implement method like `create_or_update_schedule` and `send_task_to_queue`. My implementation of `TaskScheduleHelper` looked something like below.

```
from celery.app.task import Task
class TaskScheduleHelper(object):

    @staticmethod
    def create_or_update_schedule(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create or update an ETA schedule in database in an idempotent way based on key property of TaskSchedule model.
        One should not be calling this method directly, but should use celery APIs to call this method. See Example
        below. eta and key are required keyword arguments.

        :param args: Arguments populated by @task decorator of the form <tuple>(task handler, arguments for the task
            handler)
        :param kwargs: Keyword arguments which must contain key and eta arguments. Any additional keyword
            arguments are passed as keyword arguments to the task handler
        :return: Not Applicable
        """

        # Ensure that required keyword arguments are not None
        required_kwargs = ['eta', 'key']
        for kwarg in required_kwargs:
            if kwargs.get(kwarg) is None:
                raise ValueError(f'Expected {kwarg} but got None')

        # Ensure that first argument from args list should be of type Task
        if not isinstance(args[0], Task):
            raise ValueError(f'Expected first argument to be of type Task, got {type(args[0])} instead.')

        eta = kwargs.pop('eta')
        key = kwargs.pop('key')
        task_name = args[0].name
        try:
            task_args = args[1]
        except IndexError:
            task_args = None

        # Insert or update task schedule entry in the database
        TaskSchedule.objects.update_or_create(key=key, defaults={
            'eta': eta,
            'status': TaskScheduleStatus.SCHEDULED,
            'data': {
                'handler': task_name,
                'argsrepr': task_args,
                'kwargsrepr': kwargs
            }
        })
    @staticmethod
    def send_task_to_queue(task_schedule_object):
        """
        Takes a TaskSchedule object and queues in celery for execution immediately
        :param task_schedule_object: object of type TaskSchedule which contains handler and args,
        :return: Not Applicable
        """

        # ETA of task_schedule_object should be less than current time
        assert (task_schedule_object.eta <= timezone.now())

        # status of task_schedule_object should be SCHEDULED
        assert (task_schedule_object.status == TaskScheduleStatus.SCHEDULED)

        # Fetch the task by name from app.tasks
        try:
            _task = app.tasks[task_schedule_object.handler]
        except KeyError:
            # Create an error text which can be logged using logger.error and also stored
            # in TaskSchedule object's data field for further debugging and reporting
            error_text = f'{task_schedule_object.handler} not found in app.tasks'
            logger.error("send_task_to_queue:handler_not_found", handler=task_schedule_object.handler)

            # Update the TaskSchedule object with status = error and data with execution time
            # and error_text
            TaskSchedule.objects.filter(
                key=task_schedule_object.key
            ).update(
                status=TaskScheduleStatus.ERROR,
                data=RawSQL('''jsonb_set(jsonb_set(data, '{error}', %s)::jsonb,
                            '{execution_time}', %s)''', (json.dumps(error_text), json.dumps(timezone.now().__str__())))
            )
            return

        async_task_result = _task.apply_async(task_schedule_object.argsrepr, task_schedule_object.kwargsrepr)

        # Update the task schedule with task ID so that we can query logs for this
        # particular task's execution
        # TODO (Abhishek): Set the status to executed only when CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE is disabled
        TaskSchedule.objects.filter(
            key=task_schedule_object.key
        ).update(
            status=TaskScheduleStatus.EXECUTED,
            data=RawSQL(
                '''jsonb_set(jsonb_set(data, '{task_id}', %s)::jsonb, '{execution_time}', %s)''',
                (json.dumps(async_task_result.task_id), json.dumps(timezone.now().__str__()))
            )
        )
        logger.info(f'send_task_to_queue:successfully_executed', task_key=task_schedule_object.key,
                    task_id=async_task_result.task_id)

        return async_task_result
```

I then added `create_or_update_schedule` in `celery.app.task` so that I can call it on task method.

```
from celery.app.task import Task
Task.po_schedule = TaskScheduleHelper.create_or_update_schedule
```

Now, I can schedule a task by calling `po_schedule` on it. An object will be created in the database corresponding to this task's unique key `a_unique_key`.

```
@app.task
def divide(dividend, divisor):
    return dividend/divisor

divide.po_schedule(
    (20, 5),
    key='a_unique_key',
    eta=timezone.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

I have a cron job which periodically polls on `TaskSchedule` database table for `eta`, and calls `send_task_to_queue` method of `TaskScheduleHelper`.

```
task_schedule_objects = TaskSchedule.objects.filter(status=TaskScheduleStatus.SCHEDULED,
                                                            eta__lte=timezone.now())
for task_schedule_object in task_schedule_objects:
    TaskScheduleHelper.send_task_to_queue(task_schedule_object)
```